# How can I add 2 separate menus to the mobile version of a WordPress website? [week old, still need help]

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, version

My site has 2 separate sections each with it's own menu, I can sort the menu out no problem on desktop versions - how can I add 2 separate menus for each section on mobile versions though (is it even possible?)?

[Here is my site](http://www.greencastleparish.com/wordpress), from a desktop you should see that clicking on 'Our Lady of the Wayside' brings you to a sections with a different menu.

I'm using the Jetpack plugin to create the mobile version.

I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Niall

Answer (score 0):

You can provide 2 different menus with mediaQueries, e.g.

Mobile first:

```
.mobile-menu {
   display: block;
 }

.desktop-menu {
   display: none;
  }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .desktop-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

etc.

http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/MJjmQM

Comment: Thank you HendrikEng, but I mean is it possible to have more than one menu list on a mobile and if it is, how?

Like if I have 2 different mobile pages, can they each have separate menus (say HOME, ABOUT CONTACT on one page and HOME, HISTORY, GALLERY on the other)?

Comment: Yes of course it's possible, but that would mean that you would have to read out the section/page you are in and display the right menu for the section then. I guess you are using WordPress? There should be a plugin for that.

Comment: I am indeed using WordPress.

At the moment I'm using Appearance > Menus to create a menu, there I've created 2 menus (my custom theme allows for up to 3 menus), but I don't see where I can assign a menu to certain pages.

I can't find any suitable plugins, though now that I've looked at Appearance > Menus in more depth there must be a way through that.

Comment: Can anyone provide any further advice / assistance?